# Storing a list of data temporarily future use

Tags: php

I have a search box on my website where a user can search songs. My website shows a list of all possible songs matched to users search string. Now i want to store the list of those songs into buffer or temporary storage memory so that even if user refreshes/changes a page the list stays there.

Now after some research i found the possible ways are-:

1. creating a file and storing that data into it
2. Creating a session for storing data.
3. Creating a cookie for storing list.

I don't know any other way. So what according to you is possible way to store data temporarily in PHP

Comment: you could use an in memory cache, too.  Lots of options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most definitly a job for PHP sessions.

The requirements are:

1. temporary storage that survives page reload/change: sessions do just that
2. per user cache: sessions are per-user

Of course cookies can do that as well, but they are pretty limited in size, and are always exchanged between the client and the server at each request, so it could be argued they are more suited to long surviving data, for example per-browser user preferences for a website.

Creating files should be avoided, since, for example by using a file store for sessions, PHP will do just that by itself, with an automated system able to handle session expiration that would be more tedious to implement manually.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how long your temporary list has to be around for:

1) Less than 30 minutes then PHP sessions are the way to go.

2) Hours to days then i would suggest using a cookie to store the userid/list key and a database to store the list data itself. I would probably use sqlite files in a directory and delete files over a certain age.

Just suggestions, there are many other considerations to be taken into account.